# Integral of $f \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}^2)$

Tags: integration

Let $f \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}^2)$, where $\mathbb{T}$ is the torus.

Can we somehow compare the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{T}^2}\int_{\mathbb{T}^2} \left( \int_{3x+y=z} f(w+x)f(w+y)dm_{\mathbb{T}^2}(x,y) \right) ^2dm_{\mathbb{T}^2}(z)dm_{\mathbb{T}^2}(w)$$
with $\left( \int_{\mathbb{T}^2} f(w)dm_{\mathbb{T}^2}(w) \right)^4$?

It should probably follow after a Cauchy-Schwarz and some changes of variables that the first integral is greater than or equal to the second.

Comment: I don't understand the inner integral. What is the measure $dm_{\mathbb{T}^4}(x,y)$? The notation suggests it is some sort of measure on the four-torus, but your domain of integration is $3x+y=z$ where $z$ is fixed, and so you should be integrating over a two dimensional submanifold of the four-torus?

Comment: I have edited it. Does it make more sense now?